# Find If Image Is Bright Or Dark

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I would like to know how to write a function in Python 3 using OpenCV which takes in an image and a threshold and returns either 'dark' or 'light' after heavily blurring it and reducing quality (faster the better). This might sound vague , but anything that just works will do.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Why not just type an **ImageMagick** 1-liner into the terminal that tells you the mean intensity of an image as a percentage `convert image.jpg -format "%[fx:int(mean*100)]" info:`

Comment: Not sure why you feel you need to blur?

Comment: Why not simply use a histogram based approach?

Comment: You could use `libvips` directly in Terminal `vips avg someImage.png`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try this :

```
import imageio
import numpy as np

f = imageio.imread(filename, as_gray=True)

def img_estim(img, thrshld):
    is_light = np.mean(img) > thrshld
    return 'light' if is_light else 'dark'

print(img_estim(f, 127))
```

Comment: numpy import statement missing. works great  anyway. +1

Comment: even thought that solution works i could not distinguish between light and dark images. since the difference is very small. e.g dark images some times are 136 while light images sometimes are 136 as well.. need a more smart way to figure out the grayscale than the light images

Comment: works with thrshld = 80 for bdd100k dataset. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I would not bother writing any **Python**, or loading up **OpenCV** for such a simple operation. If you absolutely have to use Python, please just disregard this answer and select a different one.

You can just use **ImageMagick** at the command-line in your Terminal to get the mean brightness of an image as a percentage, where 100 means *"fully white"* and 0 means *"fully black"*, like this:

```
convert someImage.jpg -format "%[fx:int(mean*100)]" info:
```

Alternatively, you can use `libvips` which is less common, but very fast and very lightweight:

```
vips avg someImage.png
```

The `vips` answer is on a scale of 0..255 for 8-bit images.

Note that both these methods will work for many image types, from PNG, through GIF, JPEG and TIFF.

---

However, if you really want Python/OpenCV code, I note none of the existing answers do that - some use a different library, some are incomplete, some do superfluous blurring and some read video cameras for some unknown reason, and none handle more than one image or errors. So, here's what you actually asked for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np

# Iterate over all arguments supplied
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    # Load image as greyscale
    im = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    if im is None:
        print(f'ERROR: Unable to load {filename}')
        continue
    # Calculate mean brightness as percentage
    meanpercent = np.mean(im) * 100 / 255
    classification = "dark" if meanpercent < 50 else "light"
    print(f'{filename}: {classification} ({meanpercent:.1f}%)')
```

**Sample Output**

```
OpenCVBrightOrDark.py g*png nonexistant

g30.png: dark (30.2%)
g80.png: light (80.0%)
ERROR: Unable to load nonexistant
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try this, considering `image` is a grayscale image -

```
blur = cv2.blur(image, (5, 5))  # With kernel size depending upon image size
if cv2.mean(blur) > 127:  # The range for a pixel's value in grayscale is (0-255), 127 lies midway
    return 'light' # (127 - 255) denotes light image
else:
    return 'dark' # (0 - 127) denotes dark image
```

Refer to these -
[Smoothing](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html), [Mean](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga191389f8a0e58180bb13a727782cd461), [Thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#thresholding)

Comment: The mean before and after blurring should be the same (if a proper boundary condition is used).

Comment: Its important to note that 127 is ~ half 255, and everything.Please comment your code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that is true for blur() but other blurring techniques change the mean().

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


def algo_findDark(image):
    blur = cv2.blur(image, (5, 5))
    mean = np.mean(blur)
    if mean > 85:
        return 'light'
    else:
        return 'dark'

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    check, frame = cam.read()

    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ans = algo_findDark(frame_gray)

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(frame, ans, (10, 450), font, 3, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow('video', frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say *why* you want to do this. If your use-case is for a website/app 'dark mode', because you want to invert images which look better inverted rather than dimmed, none of the solutions given here will work perfectly - because they will all have false positives/negatives, like images which are grayscale photographs (which will have few colors / histograms, but will look awful when they contain a human and are inverted, like a photo negative). These can't be fixed by hacks like blurring because it is inherently based on the semantics of the image, like whether it contains a face or not.

If that is your use-case, there doesn't seem to be any better comprehensive approach than either manually classifying every image, or using machine learning.

For the latter approach, it is is easily handled with CV methods like finetuning a small neural network; you can find a [FLOSS model](https://github.com/mattismegevand/invertornot) & API at [InvertOrNot.com](https://invertornot.com/) (using PyTorch & Onnx to train an EfficientNet CNN).