# Detect dark vs well-lit image using existing AI model

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, image-classification

I am using the below code to detect dark vs well-lit images but it is not giving accurate results and is giving very long floating values like .00000000123 etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

path = '/home/..../Downloads/normal_images'
files = os.listdir(path)
# Load the pre-trained MobileNetV2 model
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet')
x =  np.float32(0.5)

for file_name in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
# Load an image to classify

    img = cv2.imread(file_path)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, precision=20)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    probs = model.predict(img)
    prob_val = probs[0][0]
    if (prob_val > x):
            not_dark +=1
    else:
            dark +=1

print(f"No.of dark images identified: {dark}")
print(f"No.of normal images identified: {not_dark}")
```

Is my approach correct ?

Comment: I might be mistaken since I'm not familiar with the keras models, but isn't `MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet")` used for classifying images into categories based on the image content? I don't see any reason why it would give you a result based on being a light or dark image.

Comment: Your approach does not make any sense, its just classifying the first  imagenet class, not dark/light.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not the correct approach for this task.

MobileNetV2 is a model architecture that can be used for tasks such as image classification, object detection and image segmentation. When initializing it like this:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet')
```

You are loading the model weights which were produced when training on the [Imagenet dataset](https://www.image-net.org/). This dataset is created to be used in training object recognition models.

Using [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) might be a better option for your use case. [This article](https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/01/25/detecting-low-contrast-images-with-opencv-scikit-image-and-python/) describes a similar scenario and perhaps [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505906/find-if-image-is-bright-or-dark) is also relevant.